# IdentityDbContext on Sqlite

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I have been trying to use sqlite for IdentityDbContext with no luck, I am using .net core in macosx. I wonder if it's actually possible or if there is any example out there tried to search google with no luck.

Comment: Any specific errors? Are you using the right provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this example available, done on Mac OS with Asp.Net Identity, Sqlite:

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework

It starts from a sample MVC application using identity framework with SQLServer and then the author changes it to work with Sqlite.